# How can I send post request with the attached api?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send post request to this api:

[image]

Here is the sample bearer token :

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3MjMzNjEzLCJpYXQiOjE2NjcxNDcyMTMsImp0aSI6IjgyNDg0YWYzMDdmOTQ0YjNhMTQ5ZWIzN2NkNjIzNGI4IiwiaWQiOjV9.qc9fmF4B0V6NTwxsztBb6AkF78kU_06wommCa5gLgOo
```

What I tried:

Here Is my Controller for the API:

```
  Future<bool> createDisplay(
      String name, String category, String templateName, int productId) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        "https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/displays/");
    var token = localStorage.getItem('access');
    try {
      var formdata = new Map<String, dynamic>();
      formdata["name"] = name;
      formdata["category"] = category;
      formdata["template_name"] = templateName;
      formdata["products"] = productId;
      http.Response response =
          await http.post(url, body: json.encode(formdata), headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization':
            'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3MjMzNjEzLCJpYXQiOjE2NjcxNDcyMTMsImp0aSI6IjgyNDg0YWYzMDdmOTQ0YjNhMTQ5ZWIzN2NkNjIzNGI4IiwiaWQiOjV9.qc9fmF4B0V6NTwxsztBb6AkF78kU_06wommCa5gLgOo'
      });
      Future.error(response.body);
      var data = json.encode(response.body) as Map;
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        return Future.error("Its working");
      } else {
        return Future.error("Code Proble");
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      Future.error("Something is wrong with the codes");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Here is the front end code where I tried to send post request using textformfield.

```
import 'package:digitaldisplay/controllers/DisplayController.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/widgets/Display.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/widgets/ProductDisplayCard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CreateDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateDisplay({super.key});

  static const routeName = "/create-display";

  @override
  State<CreateDisplay> createState() => _CreateDisplayState();
}

class _CreateDisplayState extends State<CreateDisplay> {
  String _name = "";
  String _category = "";
  String _templateName = "";
  late final int _product;
  // String catelogImage = "";
  // String video = "";
  //String productId = "";

  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _addDisplay() async {
    var isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    bool create = await Provider.of<DisplayController>(context, listen: false)
        .createDisplay(_name, _category, _templateName, _product);
    if (create) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Created"),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Return"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Failed to create display!"),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Return"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
    }
  }

                child: Form(
                  key: _form,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please Enter a valid name";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  _name = value as String;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Name',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please enter valid category title";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  _category = value as String;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Category',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please enter valid template name";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  _templateName = value as String;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Template Name',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please enter valid product Id";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  _product = int.tryParse(value!) ?? 0;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Product Id',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _addDisplay();
                                },
                                child: Text("Add Display"),
                                style: buttonStyle2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
```

I only added the code of my frontend where I tried to pass the value. But Can't post data. I am getting an error also. The error is:

```
{"status":"error","message":{"products":["Expected a list of items but got type \"int\"."]}}
```

When I send data using postman It works perfectly. I think its for formdata though I am not sure about it. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It says it in the error there. "Expected a list of items but got type "int" In your post you are putting productId which is an int in the "products". The backend is looking for a list of products here. You can try

```
formdata["products"] = [productId];
```

to see what you come up with. I don't know what the backend is looking for in terms of the products list though. It is strange that the post with an int works in Postman too.

Comment: Its not working @returnVoid

Comment: Is there any solution? @returnVoid